# "FORGED_RELAY_MUA_TO_MX" how to fix it?

Tags: exchange-2013, spamassassin

We using exchange 2013 for are long time, but someday I try test my mail server (at https://www.mail-tester.com/) and fond some errors, most of it I fix, but left some.
Most what I do not understanding is error - "FORGED_RELAY_MUA_TO_MX"
I found some description about, needed to add header "X-Spam-Relays..."

x-spam-relays-trusted:
x-spam-relays-untrusted:
x-spam-relays-internal:
x-spam-relays-external:

First of all, we do not use relay, it is just disabled as default at our server
So that's why I can't understand what I must use here.
Added header is not are problem, but what I must wrote at it...

Answer (score 0):

Is there a problem with your normal email sending and receiving?
According to my research on the information you provided, I did not find any introduction to these properties in Exchange. If your Exchange currently does not have any functional problems, I think it is not a good choice to add it at will. Please make sure that the SPF, DKIM and DMARC in your DNS records are set correctly. This will reduce the reception of spam in your mailbox server and reduce the possibility of rejection of your email.
Please refer to: [Understanding SPF, DKIM and DMARC](https://www.smartertools.com/blog/2019/04/09-understanding-spf-dkim-dmarc)

Comment: Big thanks for answer, yes exchange work normally, but my BOSS demand solve all problems, what service https://www.mail-tester.com/ shows. I try to explain to him, about it's good work, but BOSS is BOSS. So I try find solution.
And about DKIM, as I know Exchange 2013 does not work with it.

Comment: According to my understanding, the judging criteria for this type of spam-testing websites are different from Exchange's own judging criteria. And each test site has its own process, it is difficult to ensure that you can meet the standards of all spam test sites.
As mentioned above, if there is no problem with your  Exchange server, I think it is not necessary to add header

Comment: Thanks again for answer! I corrected the Exchange configuration, add DKIM signing, wrote DMARK in DNS. Post service work fine before, now may be work better :)
And may be I can solve spamassassin rule, but i am strongly disunderstand what they want. I can add header, but does not understand what i must wrote with in it.
Last correction not for work, just for my understanding and knowledge.